# sitecore: autopopulate sublayouts from disk

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a bunch of user controls on disk that are basically sitecore sublayouts, but do not have corresponding sitecore sublayout entries.  Is there an automated way to create all of these cause entering them by hand is not an option.

Comment: I'm afraid that you will need to write some code to achieve it.

Answer (score 4):

Use Sitecore Rocks plugin for Visual Studio. It can bind physical files to (new/existing) Sitecore items.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing out of the box. @VIKRAM is right, you're going to have to write some import code if you want them in. That would only take you 10% of the way there however, there would be no obvious way to do the supporting meta architecture, datasource templates, placeholder settings, insert options and so on.

Your only real option, is creating them by hand. And you rule that out yourself.

Comment: yeah, it would be miserable to create by hand.  But that's what I've been doing on an as needed basis.  The thing is, the previous vendor used a single sublayout then determined the ascx file based on the template name.  This just seems like a bad idea